# Is IntPtr.Zero equivalent to null?

Tags: c#, file-io, asynchronous

I am trying to setup `ReadFile` to run asynchronously and according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx), I need to set `lpNumberOfBytesRead` to `null`:

> "Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results."

For example, if I have the following:

```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern bool ReadFile(
     IntPtr hFile,
     out byte[] aBuffer,
     int cbToRead,
     IntPtr cbThatWereRead,
     ref OVERLAPPED pOverlapped
  );
```

and I call it like this (with the intention of having the 4th parameter being null):

```
Win32API.ReadFile(readHandle, out data_read, Win32API.BUFFER_SIZE, IntPtr.Zero, ref over_lapped);
```

will that be the same as calling it with null?  If not, what should I change in the declaration or in the function call itself?

I was also curious if I should be using `SafeHandle` or `HandleRef` instead of `IntPtr` for the `hFile` reference?  I know to make sure that I close the handle with `CloseHandle(IntPtr)` when I'm done with it, just not sure if there is any othe reason to use the other two options over `IntPtr`.  I am also tryingn to avoid using unsafe code.

EDIT: As it turns out, I shouldnt be setting the fourth parameter to `IntPtr.Zero` anyway, because even though I am running asynchronously, it could still return right away.  See [Asynchronous Disk I/O](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932). Ahh, I love contradicting stories.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

For P/Invoke purposes like you've listed, you should use `IntPtr.Zero` in place of `NULL`. Note that this is not equivalent to the C# `null` keyword, however.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot assign null to a value-type. A reference-type can be null, as in, not referring to an object instance, but a value-type always has a value.

IntPtr.Zero is just a constant value that represents a null pointer.

Comment: Apparently IntPtr is Chuck Norris. It can compare to null, but never be true in such comparison.

Answer (score 9):

Be aware that there is a bug (feature??) in C# >= 2.0, where

```
if (IntPtr.Zero == null)
{
    // Won't enter here
}
```

will compile correctly, but it won't ever enter in the `if`.

I opened an issue on the [github of roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18975) and they replied that they won't fix it because there are projects that are built with warnings-as-errors. Still there is a partial fix for this: there is a `strict` compilation mode that generates this warning:

```
<Features>strict</Features>
```

Comment: Sorry for the back post, but that isn't a bug as IntPtr.Zero is not equal to null - so that if statement wouldn't work.

Comment: @Kobunite Then try writing `if (IntPtr.Zero == "Hello")` and see what happens. There will be a compile-time error... The problem is that there is no warning that the comparison is impossible, and no error. The code is simply removed by the compiler. See the IL code generated http://goo.gl/6zpPxN

Comment: Sorry to necro, but it compiles because it's effectively using the `==` operator overload to implicit cast as `(IntPtr?)IntPtr.Zero == (IntPtr?)null`

Comment: @Marc The problem isn't in the missing error... http://goo.gl/7o2fKM the problem is that if you try doing `5 == null` you'll get a warning, but if you do `IntPtr.Zero == null` you won't get a warning. Interestingly the compiler knows that the equality is impossible, and in fact it will remove the code.

Comment: Why this compiles I don't know, IntPtr is a struct, should not be comparable to null, should not even compile.