# Is there a way to create a null value for .NET outside C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I am using the .NET support in a 3rd party imaging application where it allows one to use .NET assemblies. The only catch is you have to call/create things using the fully qualified name, for instance:

```
NewDotNetObject "System.Object";
NewDotNetObject "System.Drawing.Color" 1 2 3;
(NewDotNetMethodCall "System.Math").Abs -45;
...
```

I am trying to use a method where I need to pass a `null` value. But I don't know the fully qualified name for `null`.

Can a `null` value be created this way?

Comment: I believe that's something that your 3rd party imaging application would have to address.  Surely it provides ways to encode a `null` value for use with .NET calls right?

Comment: This looks like a wrapper language, it would have to define a notation for null. Your samples eem incomlete.

Comment: Thanks guys I was assuming so too, but its Null value seems to work differently. I might have to dig deeper, but wanted to check just in case.

Comment: It might help if you identify either the third party imaging application, or at least the language it uses.

Comment: I would but it's proprietary software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if that is the right for you, but there is System.DBNull which represents no data.

Or can you use null pointers?

```
System.IntPtr.Zero
```

Comment: Thanks I can, is a null pointer the same as a null value? Would .NET recognize this?

Comment: yes, thats right.. and IntPtr.Zero isn't the correct answer here, [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456861/is-intptr-zero-equivalent-to-null)