# C# Can I check if an IntPtr is null?

Tags: c#, null, intptr

I have an IntPtr field in my C# class.
It holds a reference to an object in a C++ library.

```
protected IntPtr ThingPtr;
```

At some stage I may or may not initialise it.

```
ThingPtr = FunctionInMyCplusplusLibrary();
```

I'm wondering if checking whether it is null makes sense in this context (to check whether it has been intialised or not)

```
if(ThingPtr == null)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Never. ever. presume ANYTHING to be initialized. So yes, it does make complete sense!

Comment: An `IntPtr` can never be `null`.  Use `ThingPtr == IntPtr.Zero` instead.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but this is an answer that you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456861/is-intptr-zero-equivalent-to-null

Comment: Structs are value types and cannot be null while objects are reference types and can be null.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`IntPtr` is a value type and cannot be null.

You want to check whether it has a value of (address) 0:

```
if (ThingPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
```

Comment: An alternative is default(IntPtr) which I suspect is equivalent to IntPtr.Zero. If you want to specify the default value for a parameter, IntPtr.Zero won't work, but you can specify default(IntPtr), for example void TestMethod ( IntPtr p = default(IntPtr) )

Answer (score 4):

IntPtr is a struct it can never be null, your library may return the equivalent of null but I expect that would be zero.

Answer (score 3):

You can use IntPtr.Zero for null, however it's not equivalent to C# null value.