# Overstepping Anonymous Log on Null Exception in c# of form authentication SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting Null Reference Exception when running c# code from https://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com.I have tried this link ,https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaitanya_medikonduri/2010/03/18/forms-authentication-sample-and-windows-2008/  giving dummy value to user identity to overstep Anonymous Log on Null Exception, but I am still getting the exception and I can't go any further. How can I fix it? Some one can give me any idea or any reference link for me to read and try? I am totally lost.
[image: Screenshot]

> ```
>    public void GetUserInfo(out IIdentity userIdentity, out IntPtr userId)
>    {
> ```

```
       // If the current user identity is not null,

       // set the userIdentity parameter to that of the current user 

       if (HttpContext.Current != null

             && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
       {

           userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

       }

       else

       // The current user identity is null. This happens when the user attempts an anonymous logon.

       // Although it is ok to return userIdentity as a null reference, it is best to throw an appropriate

       // exception for debugging purposes.

       // To configure for anonymous logon, return a Gener
       {

           userIdentity = new GenericIdentity("test");

           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(true);

       }
       // initialize a pointer to the current user id to zero

       userId = IntPtr.Zero;

   }
```

Comment: According to [Is IntPtr.Zero equivalent to null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456861/is-intptr-zero-equivalent-to-null), IntPtr.Zero is not equivalent to null, but it still gives you an error. Try `userId = new IntPtr(0);` and let me know what it says.

Comment: @Keyur PATEL. in my program, It is still showing the exception after the change. and userIdentity is still null and userId is 0.

Comment: Try adding a clause to your if statement: `if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null)`

Comment: still Null. The code can't go through.

Comment: No change, still got exception.

Comment: Does it mean my Extension dll file is something wrong?

Comment: Possibly, I'm still looking for ways to fix it though.

Comment: Thanks, I am also looking now.

Comment: Delete the older dll files and paste into the right places , modified codes as mentioned in blog before make it stop getting this Anonymous is not Configured Exception error. But I am no hunt for another error -which is-how to successfully register into the database.

Comment: What's the new error? Maybe add it to your question or post a new one.

Comment: @Keyur PATEL thanks by the way you help me point out my dll issue. Okay I am posting my next question on a thread. If you are keen, please take a look too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505229/register-new-user-into-database-in-ssrs-form-authentication