# How do I monitor clipboard content changes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I want to have this feature in my C# program: When the user do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or Copy anywhere (i.e. when the clipboard content changes), my program will get notified, and check whether the content met certain criteria, if so, become the active program, and process the content, etc.

I can get the contents out from `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`, however, I don't know how to monitor the content changes from the clipboard.

If using Windows Vista or later, use `AddClipboardFormatListener` as in John Knoeller's answer, for Windows XP, I have to use the older, more fragile `SetClipboardViewer` API, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: How to do this in WPF is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33018459/2122718

Comment: [SharpClipboard](https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/SharpClipboard) as a library could be of more benefit as it encapsulates the same features into one fine component library. You can then access its `ClipboardChanged` event and detect various data-formats when they're cut/copied.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052(VS.85).aspx) provided by Win32 API (through P/Invoke).

Here is a page which contains code to set one up in C#: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c7315/

Comment: SetClipboardViewer is an fragile, older API, you should not be using it in new code.  use AddClipboardFormatListener instead.

Comment: Likewise, you can also try [SharpClipboard](https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/SharpClipboard). It provides a `ClipboardChanged` event that allows you to filter various data-formats whenever they're cut/copied and get the clipboard content.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Answer (score 57):

I've written up a small utility class that uses the [AddClipboardFormatListener function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function with a [Message-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx#message_only) window to do just this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides notifications when the contents of the clipboard is updated.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ClipboardNotification
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the contents of the clipboard is updated.
    /// </summary>
    public static event EventHandler ClipboardUpdate;

    private static NotificationForm _form = new NotificationForm();

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="ClipboardUpdate"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments for the event.</param>
    private static void OnClipboardUpdate(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = ClipboardUpdate;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hidden form to recieve the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message.
    /// </summary>
    private class NotificationForm : Form
    {
        public NotificationForm()
        {
            NativeMethods.SetParent(Handle, NativeMethods.HWND_MESSAGE);
            NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
            {
                OnClipboardUpdate(null);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    public const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
    public static IntPtr HWND_MESSAGE = new IntPtr(-3);

    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx#message_only
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649033%28VS.85%29.aspx
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
}
```

This class assumes that the notifications are always needed for the duration of the applications lifetime, however it could be modified to provide the ability to unsubscribe via the [RemoveClipboardFormatListener function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  if required.

Comment: Nice. Did you ever update this to incorporate XP as well?

Comment: @tofutim No, I'm not sure what API is available on XP machines which can do this

Comment: [this is for XP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2226957/3331861)

Comment: Likewise, you can also try [SharpClipboard](https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/SharpClipboard). It provides a `ClipboardChanged` event that allows you to filter various data-formats whenever they're cut/copied and get the clipboard content.

Comment: Note: You should always remove your window from the clipboard notification change before you exit your app.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with pinvoke to the Win32 API [AddClipboardFormatListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649033(VS.85).aspx)

The listener is a window handle (Form.Handle), and the form will be notified of changes with a 
[WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649021(VS.85).aspx) notification

It is a more robust replacement for the older `SetClipboardViewer` API.

Comment: Thanks. but on the msdn page, the minimum OS requirement for this API is Vista. is that true? (I'm still under XP though. in fact, my users will be using XP, too.)

Comment: Yes, minimum requirement is Vista. If you are on XP then you have no choice than to use SetClipboarViewer.  Be aware that SetClipboardViewer is fragile, although you should have no problems if _your_ code is correct and you are the _only_ viewer.

Comment: Ok, I will be very cautious. Your answer would otherwise be the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Win32 API contains a function SetClipboardViewer.

[Here is a pretty good (from a quick glance) write up.](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx)

Comment: that's a good example, too. Thanks!