# Would it be technically difficult to recreate windows for workgroup clipboard on windows 7 with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, win32com

In the old days of windows workgroup 3.11 there was the possibility to copy and paste on the network.

This feature has been removed which is weird today as we are in sharing information era !

So would it be technically difficult to recreate windows for workgroup clipboard on windows 7 in c# ? What API method would be mandatory to use ? Anyone did already try ?

Comment: Remote Desktop shares clipboard between the two PCs. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically difficult can be seen as a matter of opinion or skill set, but it appears that it is possible at least. I've never had a reason to do it myself but you could probably look into the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226920/how-to-monitor-clipboard-content-changes-in-c), and broadcast any clipboard changes to LAN peers. I'd probably use UDP broadcast for the actual sharing.