# Sending keys silently

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to pass messages between a vba application (in powerpoint- during a slideshow) and a .net application I wrote.

The only method I could think of, is sending keystrokes.

However, this method causes the powerpoint to lose focus.

can you suggest a solution ?

Comment: http://damianblog.com/2009/07/05/excel-wcf/

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a solution without knowing what you intend to do (what messages?, how often?, Based on what Event/data/time?). If you wrote the App then SendKeys is probably NOT the way forward.

Comment: I have a background .net application, and I'm trying to make it aware of the current powerpoint state. in otherwords - whether the slideshow is on, and what slide is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting way of communication between vba and .net, without file system manipulation, sockets or external objects.

First, We register powerpoint evets, as such:

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=327

Second, We update the clipboard in VBA on the presentation-start event:

http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/ManipulateClipboard.htm

Third, We use a clipboard a listener on .net:

[How do I monitor clipboard content changes in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226920/how-to-monitor-clipboard-content-changes-in-c)

Last, We restore the original clipboard value on presentation-end event

Answer (score 1):

If all happens on the same machine, the easiest way maybe is to let the PPT write its status into the registry from where the other application reads it out (`GetSetting(), SaveSetting()`).

If PTT and the other process run on different machines, you could think of writing out the status into a small text file which can be read out asynchronously.

Another way of (synchronous) communication between two processes/applications on different machines is to use [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and send information across the network.

Comment: The two apps are running on the same machine, I don't like the whole concept of polling for file-system changes, because it's error-prone (permissions, etc.)

Comment: in this case use `SaveSetting()` on the PPT-VBA side to push info into the registry and `=GetSetting()` to retrieve them from your other application