# How OneNote accesses url of copied text from firefox, how can I use this in my app

Tags: windows, winapi

When you copy text from a webpage in firefox (a non microsoft product) into OneNote it adds the url of the webpage along with the copied text as "Pasted from" as in the following example:

```
Apache OpenOffice is an open-source office productivity software suite 

Pasted from <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openoffice>
```

How OneNote access the url info of the copied text from a non microsoft app. How can I access similar information programmatically in my apps using c++/C# or other technologies? Is there some api to access additional information from system clipboard like url, source application, source file etc?

Comment: The clipboard itself is "global" to the user and can be observed for changes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226920/how-to-monitor-clipboard-content-changes-in-c

Comment: Also note that some web sites (news websites, blogs, etc) use JavaScript to insert some hidden attribution text in the selection that will be included when you copy the text.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [the documentation for the HTML clipboard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), Web browsers can provide an optional `SourceURL` to specify where the HTML came from.

Comment: can such info be accessed for other apps like if I copy text from a pdf into m$ Word, the filename of the pdf document also gets copied. It would be great for collecting material for personal research and then later be able to get the source. I mean generally what additional information can be programmatically accessed along with copied content on windows platform, where can I find documentation or other reference material on this topic.

Comment: Please only one question per SO post. Also, writing "m$" is going to make certain people unwilling to help you further.