# Clipboard surveilance

Tags: security, clipboard, logfile

1. Does windows clipboard store copied Strings locally, or, as with files, does it only deal with pointers?
2. If it does, is it possible to modify the clipboard to make a logfile of all Strings that are routed  through it?

I would imagine this could be a dangerous tool against people who hide high entropy passwords somewhere deep in their system (maybe encrypted) and then just copy paste them where needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible -- there are plenty of commercial keyloggers ([this one, for example](http://www.ardamax.com/keylogger/)) that can log text copied to the clipboard.

You're absolutely right that this is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like you can actually log everything that goes through the clipboard with the [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649033(VS.85).aspx)  API call: [relevant SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226920/how-to-monitor-clipboard-content-changes-in-c/2226952#2226952). Simply pass the handle of your window in as the only parameter. The [`SetClipboardViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will also work for older versions of Windows.

This is certainly a security risk.

This [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/where-is-the-clipboard/f6ee8fec-2859-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) suggests that the clipboard is stored entirely in memory, and [this part of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649014(v=vs.85).aspx) talks about receiving a global memory handle on the clipboard.