# ClipBoard Monitor C#

Tags: c#, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clipboard event C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c)

Hi,

Can I monitor the clipboard continuously for any copy operations? I'm using C#

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c

Comment: [SharpClipboard](https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/SharpClipboard) is a really handy .NET library for monitoring the system clipboard. Do try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some more helpful links, with source code:

Monitoring Activity: http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c7315

A viewer: http://www.doogal.co.uk/clip.php

Comment: Likewise, [SharpClipboard](https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/SharpClipboard) as a library could be of more benefit as it encapsulates the same features into one.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the Win32 API, this [page](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx) has a guide on how to do it all

Comment: This answer has already been provided for the question linked to by @Jason Evans. There's no need to post it again.