# Copy Tooltip text from RichTextBox instead of Controls.image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, richtextbox, clipboard

**The problem**

So I have a `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`, which contains `Paragraph`s, containing `Run`s, containing either text or `System.Windows.Controls.Image` objects.

The images have `Tooltip`s on them, describing what they do (not that you can see them when you hover in the `RichTextBox`.)

When I select and copy (`ctrl-c`) the contents of the `RichTextBox`, I want to copy the description of the image, rather than the image itself; and keep the rest of the text the same.

So, for example:

[image: INFO:] program is working!

would be copied as

"INFO: program is working!"

**My ideas so far**

I guess I would have to manually capture the event when text is copied from the `RichTextBox` (is there one?), and replace the contents of the clipboard by hand? Does the clipboard store the `Tooltip` information when the `Image` is copied? If not, is there any other way I could automatically get that information?

Comment: Text can be copied with the mouse, so it's more like you need to listen to Clipboard changes ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6458030/1997232), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3836169/1997232), doesn't looks good tbh) or completely wrap copying functionality (e.g. button `Copy all as text` or `Copy selected`), then you should have opportunity to go through selection of `RichTextBox` and replace images ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4404516/1997232) ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment by @Sinatr says, the best way is to use the clipboard change event handlers and manually replace.