# Binding the Copy/Paste button to the clipboard

Tags: .net, winforms

I have 3 buttons (in WinForm) Cut/Copy/Paste.

I need to bind the enabled and disabled state for each of them in dependence if the Clipboard contains or not "MyObject"s list.

How can I automatize that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to know when the Clipboard has changed, a great wrapper for this is answered in:
[Clipboard event C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp/1394225#1394225)

Handle the `ClipboardChanged` event and process accordingly.

Comment: It works only on the first opened form... say if I have MyForm1 and myForm2, so I open myForm1, then MyForm2, the event ClipboardChanged will be raised only in MyForm1

Comment: If you use the control-based example, it must be added to each form and the event registered.  This works perfectly fine in tests I tried.

Comment: I am talking about "same" form (MyForm), opened multiple times.

Comment: Win32 doesn't care what the base .NET class is - works just fine.  Pull the relevant code from the linked ClipboardMonitor class to not be a control.  Just use SetClipboardViewer and others directly.