# Copy content from one system to another

Tags: c#, .net, networking, system

I have 2 computer system which is connected to same network (Sys1,Sys2). If I copy any content from Sys1, I need to paste to Sys2.

- My thought process (.net project)

  - create a application which will run when system start up.
  - when I do copy I have to track, then I will save the copied content to DataBase.
  - while trying to paste (Sys2) I will get the content from Database.

Anyone please suggest, is this one work out? And also please guide to do the Task.

Thanks in advance 
Ramesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this approach would work.

Note: consider using existing tools to synchronize content instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Random guess: maybe you are looking for event when something added to clipboard to implemet something similar to clipboard for remote desktop... Check following for info: [Clipboard event C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks Alexei, you are given a positive energy for me . but i d't know where to stat. my main problem is how to track Copy process? :(

Comment: It is kind of hard to figure your problems out from the way you've asked question... But it is still unclear what the problem - you know how many items to copy (not sure if content is just files or something else) - so assuming you know how to copy an item it should be easy to know how many items still left to copy...

Comment: content may be anything (files,text .. etc).consider an Example: i have one file in my Desktop (TestFile.txt), if i do right on the file the click copy, in the same time i have to call my application for saving the Testfile.txt to database. so my question is how do i know copy option is clicked or not ?

Comment: I'm lost. Please re-read and edit your question to actually contain what you want to ask. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to Move file to network location.

File.Copy will not work for UNC path. MoveFile (P/Invoke) will work.

CopyFile does not exist. So First use File.Copy to create a local temp file, then call MoveFile.

c# syntax

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int MoveFile([In(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpExistingFileName, [In(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpNewFileName);
```

Comment: How do i tack copy process ?.