# Comparing IDataObject from the Clipboard

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, clipboard

My WPF application checks the data on the clipboard to see if it can work with the data or not. Because I set some buttons to be enabled/disabled based on the data (via an `ICommand` implementation), this code is called frequently.

The work to determine if my application can work with the data can be non-trivial at times, and thus is causing my application to "hang" randomly. I don't believe I can push this work off to another thread since the WPF runtime is expecting a response quickly.

In order to solve this issue, I thought I would compare the `IDataObject`s (the current one from the clipboard vs. a cached one from the previous attempt. A straight comparison (and even an `object.ReferenceEquals` does not return the desired results, so I thought I would try the method `Clipboard.IsCurrent`. The description sounds like exactly what I want, but when I evaluate the following:

```
Clipboard.IsCurrent(Clipboard.GetDataObject())
```

the result is `false`. The current workaround is to compare the data formats on the IDataObject, but that's not a good answer since my application can handle some files from the file system, but not all. So even though the formats are identical, the result on whether my application can handle the data may not always be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `IsCurrent` does not work in conjunction with `GetDataObject`. [MSDN's description of `OleIsCurrentClipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms679667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which `IsCurrent` uses internally) is quite explicit about this:

OleIsCurrentClipboard only works for the data object used in the OleSetClipboard function. **It cannot be called by the consumer of the data object to determine if the object that was on the clipboard at the previous OleGetClipboard call is still on the clipboard.**

A workaround could be to subscribe to clipboard updates (see e.g.
[Clipboard event C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp)) and evaluate the data only when it changes, potentially in a background thread.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the work around you linked to, though never really understood why `IsCurrent` wasn't working as expected until you explained it. Thanks!