# Compare two Clipboard IDataObject in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I'm using [Clipboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp) to copy data from clipboard to my application which includes a Microsoft Word.

it will paste data to the word as soon as the user hits copy anywhere in windows. But I don't want to paste the same data if the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> twice. 
Now as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010724/comparing-idataobject-from-the-clipboard?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggests, I can't use `IsCurrent` to compare `DataObjects`

So I'm doing it this way:

```
if (Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText).ToString()!=oldData)
  {
     //Paste and stuffs
     oldData= Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText).ToString();
  }
```

But it only works if the data contains some texts and I'm getting null reference error if it doesn't. 
So is there any way to know if the `DataObject` contains anthing else than text (say `Bitmap`) and be able to compare them?

Comment: The only thing in this code that could cause a null pointer error is the `.ToString()` call. You could just fetch `Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText)` into an Object variable in advance and check it for null, you know... that's kind of the standard way to avoid null pointers in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use method ContainsData to check the type of object exists or not

```
  if (Clipboard.ContainsData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text))
        {
            //do something
        }
```

you can explore DataFormats class for formats suited to your needs

Comment: Thanks. That's the way I came up with.