# subscribe to clipboard event from within browser

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, activex, clipboard

Using the Win32 API it is possible to subscribe to clipboard events ([Clipboard event C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp)).

Is it possible to do this from within an Active X Control or SilverLight within a web page?

My scenario is that I would like to know when something new has arrived in the clipboard but I am in a web page within Internet Explorer (min version 8).

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 5 you can enable trusted applications in browser:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx
In trusted applications you can use p/invoke to call WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no you cannot @Vlad I was looking to be notifed when something new has arrived - it doesn't seem possible