# Check if clipboard has data, paste into textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clipboard, copy-paste

iam trying to paste the data gathered from the clipboard in a textbox (C#)

In this case i copy something into the clipboard

```
Clipboard.SetText("Hello, clipboard");
```

How can i do that at the exact moment that clipboard has something,(or when the users does a ctrl+c) perform a copy event into a textbox?

i have tried with this code;My textbox is tbData:

```
private void tbData_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
    {
        tbData.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        Clipboard.Clear();
    }
}
```

but i get this exception:

> Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp

Comment: From memory, you need to dirty your hand a bit and go into native calls. I should have an example I can post later today if you want for an app I wrote that monitors the clipboard ...

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to wire-up an event handler for clipboard update event. But this required using P/Invoke to DllImport("user32.dll") to get to event. See this article http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-monitor-for-clipboard-changes-using-addclipboardformatlistener/

Then you can do this.....

```
//register clipboard change
            YourAppName.ClipboardUpdate += new EventHandler(ClipboardChanged);
private void ClipboardChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        //clipboard not empty and these are the formats I am only interested in
        if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText) || iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) || iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Html)) 
        { 
         //do work
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus, that's exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
{
    returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
    Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html);
}
```