# Stop a loop without threading C#

Tags: c#, revit-api

sorry if this is a silly question, I am new to C#, so please give me a break.

I am working on Revit API. currently, Revit API doesn't support multi-threading operations.
my question is how to stop a loop without calling a new thread?

I am trying to get a snapshot and I am waiting for the user to pick a snap, so I put an infinite loop till the condition meets

```
while (!Clipboard.ContainsImage()) //loop till user get a clipboard image
                {

                }
```

but what if I want to abort this???
I have tried

```
private void Abort_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            abort = true;
        }
    }
```

but this method requires threading ....any suggestions!!

Comment: You can use the `break` command to break out of the while loop.

Comment: Did you take a look at your cpu load with that `!Clipboard.ContainsImage()` That is not a good idea!

Comment: Never **EVER** wait for a operation to be completed by using a `while` loop

Comment: How about [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: @RononDex why? Maybe I want to increment a progress bar every second while a task is running. Using a `while` in that instance makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Gusdor yes, when using something like `Thread.Sleep` it would make sense, however it is still a bad practise. A much better way would be to use events

Comment: @RononDex if the requirement is "updating a progress bar every second", how do events help. It cannot be a cooperative update; you will need a `while(true){ UpdateProgress(); cancelToken.WaitHandle.Wait(1000); cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); }`

Comment: @Gusdor, you could use a Timer instead of a while loop for this.

Comment: @RononDex but _why?_ All you get is more complicated code with callbacks and invokes flying around..

Comment: @Gusdor Because that results in nicer / easier to read code. Furthermore the built-in timer should be much more error proof then a simple while loop. Also why reinvent the wheel and code it on your own? We are drifting a bit off-topic here. In the end it is a design philosophy and everyone handles this different.

Comment: @RononDex you know what. I just implemented your `Timer` based solution while my task blocks on `CancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne` and I tend to agree. The code is leaner.

Comment: @Gusdor what do you mean by ***my task blocks on*** and ***leaner*** ?

Comment: @RononDex **learner**: less code, easier to read. **Blocks on**: I used the task cancellation waithandle (mutex) to wait for the duration (instead of loops and sleeps) and still observe cancellations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into asynchronous processing patterns in Revit - check for instance [The Building Coders description of IExternalEvent](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/idling-enhancements-and-external-events.html#4).

It might take a little while to wrap your head around it, but let me try to explain:

Split your code up into two parts: The first part runs up until the moment you ask the user to pick a snap (I'm assuming this happens in another application?). In a separate thread, poll the clipboard (or [register your application as a clipboard viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp)) in your while loop. Don't forget to `Sleep()` while you're polling! As soon as your polling thread finds a picture, create an instance of an `IExternalEvent` subclass and post it to Revit. When Revit has some spare time, it will execute the `Execute` method, passing in a `UIApplication` that you can use to do the rest of your code.

Revit doesn't let you access it's API from multiple threads *at the same time*, but during the `Execute` method of an `IExternalEvent` subclass, you are guaranteed to be in the correct thread for running code.

You can also look into the `OnIdling` event - basically, this gets called each time Revit has some spare time too. So instead of using a `while` loop in a separate thread, you could just place your clipboard checking code in the event handler for the `OnIdling` event and create a mechanism (a flag) to tell you wether you are currently waiting for a snap or not...