How to detect clipboard content change in WPF
I am working on a WPF application in which I need to maintain state of Paste menu options. I think the best way would be to detect when clipboard content changes. I have seen a couple of techniques for doing this; one nice simple one applies to WinRT; another is contained in an answer to this question: How do I monitor clipboard content changes in C#?. The approach involves a Win32 API call to register with the clipboard viewer chain and a Forms window to receive clipboard notification messages. It seems to me there must be a better way. If I have to make the Win32 call, is there a cleaner way to receive/process the notifications than set up a Forms window? Can't it be done with through WPF application window?

Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174892/background-clipboard-monitoring-in-wpf-with-mvvm-and-binding-copied-context-in-v
