# How to prevent Copy/Past event in word?

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anybody please suggest how to handle Cut,Copy and Paste events in Word/Excel  using C#? (winform). I want to deny copy/paste events when i'm running my app and after that opening word/excel

Comment: I don't think you can catch the Word/Excel events. You can however do it for the whole system but that will impact other applications aswell.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to prevent those events. If you're looking to secure documents against copying, see what Office itself can do or use PDF.

Comment: Wouldn't be much of a word processor if you deny copy/paste

Comment: I think what you can do is to [monitor the ClipBoard events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp)  through your Winform project, but it will affect all application.

Comment: I thinking about to use hook prevent copy/paste events

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do that is to open Word in sandbox application or some frame and remove these shortcuts in sandbox-frame-enviroment. Also this word isntance SHOULD have addon/app/addin that disables UI buttons for that. There is not other way because events belongs to system Clipboard not to word and blocking them can make whole system break.