# Saving a screenshot from clipboard

Tags: c#, uwp, clipboard

I'm trying to save images from clipboard. This works well, if I copy something from Paint for example. If I take a screenshot, the `Clipboard.GetContent().AvailableFormats` shows me 0 items - so no Bitmap Image.

But when I put a timer for 1ms which gets the clipboard data, everything works fine. Since I think depending on random time is dirty, I would like to call something like `WaitForClipboard`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve it by handle clipboard update event. You could reference the below link for how to handle clipboard event.

[Clipboard event C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp/33018459#33018459)

In the handler of clipboard update event, you could use  the `Clipboard.GetContent().AvailableFormats` to check for available content.