# How to Paste to a Text Box (C#) when copied a text from windows

Tags: c#, copy, paste

I need to copy a text from notepad or in some text editor, When I press Ctrl+C, that text should automatically paste on my text box in my application which has opened.

How to do that?

Comment: do you mean ctrl+v?

Comment: How are you opening a notepad? Is it from your application? or directly from Windows OS? You may need to use OS commands to switch to your application then focus on the text box and then paste it there.

Comment: I guess what you want isn't just copy and paste, is it? Please describe in detail what you want to do.

Comment: https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/monitor-clipboard-in-c/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp

Comment: When I select a text and press Ctrl+C it should be automatically paste in my opened c# program's text box